# Ошибка в реализации malloc для массива структур

Tags: c

Разбираюсь с языком СИ, возникла проблема при использовании malloc для собственной структуры, чего ток не читал и не пробовал, при попытке присвоения выводит ошибку доступа к памяти.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdlib.h>
using namespace std;
struct TrieElement
{
    string val;
    size_t l_pos, r_pos;
};
int main()
{
    TrieElement* arr;
    arr = (TrieElement*)malloc(sizeof(TrieElement));
    arr[0].val = "ddd";
    return 0;
}
```

Не ругайте за частичное использование с++, сначала изучал именно его.
Ответы вида "Используйте new, delete" прошу не писать, ибо требуется именно разобраться с СИ реализацией подобной задачи.

Comment: При использовании `malloc` конструктор не вызывается. Вот и выводится мусор. И это — не *частичное использование* С++, это — частичное применение С в С++... Смешение языков до добра не доводит...

Comment: Дело в том, что пробовал arr[0].l_pos = -1; таким образом сам инициализировать, но всё равно выдаёт тот же мусор.

Comment: Целочисленный тип `std::size_t` — беззнаковый. После преобразования значения `-1` в `std::size_t` получится `std::numeric_limits<std::size_t>::max()` (оно же `SIZE_MAX`). Ну и используйте `new`/`delete`, чтобы автоматически вызывались конструкторы/деструкторы.

Comment: Спасибо большое, тут разобрался! Сейчас немного подкорректирую вопрос!

Comment: Подкорректировал вопрос, проблема с самим массивом структур и malloc осталась, только немного поменялся сам итоговый вопрос. Прошу прощения, если появляются тупые ошибки.

Comment: Для начала стоит определиться с языком, если разбираетесь с языком С, то и пишите на языке С. Соответственно никаких `<iostream>` `using namespace std;` `string`  в коде быть не должно.

Comment: `/* arr[0].val = "ddd";*/    new ( & arr [ 0  ] . val ) string ( "ddd" ) ;`

Comment: `std::malloc` в C++ нужно использовать очень осторожно — очень легко наткнуться на неопределённое поведение. Вероятно, невозможно, не используя `new`, сконструировать объект `TrieElement` без неопределённого поведения (но это не точно).

Comment: Если я правильно понял, то раз конструктор структуры не вызывается, то и конструктор для строки ```string``` тоже, в следствии имеем ошибку доступа к памяти, так?

Comment: `malloc` выделяет память с мусором. операция `new(адрес памяти)тип;` вызывает констркутор объекта в данном участке памяти.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Достаточно было лишь осознать, что malloc не вызывает конструкторов, поэтому нужно всё инициализировать ручками, рабочий итог:

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
struct TrieElement
{
    char* val;
    size_t l_pos, r_pos;
};
int main()
{
    TrieElement* arr;
    arr = (TrieElement*)malloc(sizeof(TrieElement));
    arr[0].val = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char));
    arr[0].val[0] = 'd';
    printf("%c", arr[0].val[0]);
    return 0;
}
```

Возможно кому-то сэкономит время:)

Comment: Сомнительная идея изучать С, компилируя код С++-компилятором. В С нет конструкторов, `TrieElement() : l_pos(-1), r_pos(-1) {}` не сработает.

Comment: Прошу прощения, забыл этот кусок кода удалить!

Comment: И пространств имен в С нет... `using namespace std;`

Comment: Увидел, исправил!

Comment: `arr[0].val = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char));` -- вы уверены, что хотите хранить именно 1 символ, а  не С-шную строку (они должны завершаться нулевым байтом, чтобы стандартные функции работы со строками вели себя верно), хоть даже и из одного символа?

Comment: Здравствуйте! Один символ был именно для примера, в своём коде нулевой байт учёл.